# question - XSL search using values from a variable against multiple XML files

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a tokenized variable that contains list of filenames from a .txt of a directory listing. I want to look for those filenames in a number of xml files in a number of subdirectories. If the filename is found, I want to output that "filename" was found in "xmlfile".

There are a lot of xml directories and they are not static. Same with xml files. The filenames are not tagged in the xml, so I'm just looking for their plain text occurence in the file.

Any help would be appreciated.

to make the examples easier - I want to use

$filenames_to_find (tokenized list of filenames from a .txt directory listing)

to search against

```
dir1/*.xml  
dir2/*.xml
```

with the output being

filename was found in xmlfilename

---

I'm using an academic version of Oxygen XML so I think I have Saxon through that and I have the standalone Saxon file for running this from the command line.

Thanks to the answers so far and more google searches, I've gotten this, which doesn't work. I know it's broken, but I don't know how to fix it!

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0"
    expand-text="yes"
    >

    <xsl:variable name="filenames_from_directory_listing" as="xs:string" select="unparsed-text('filenames_from_directory_listing.txt')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="filenames_to_find" select="tokenize($filenames_from_directory_listing, '\s+')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="collection('.?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="xml_filenames" select="."/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$filenames_to_find">
                    <xsl:if test="(contains($t, .))">
                        <xsl:message>{document-uri($xml_filenames)} contains {.}</xsl:message>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any suggestions? Clearly I am an XSL novice. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: You can use `collection` and `uri-collection` with Saxon to load (`collection`) files respectively load their URI (`collection`) from a directory e.g. `uri-collection('?select=*.xml')` gives you a sequence of URIs in the current directory. See "Processing directories" in http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.8/sourcedocs/collections.html.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Saxon, or another product that maps collection URIs to directory filenames in a similar way, you can do

```
<xsl:for-each select="collection('.?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')">
   <xsl:variable name="doc" select="."/>
   <xsl:for-each select="$filenames">
     <xsl:if test="some $t in $doc//text() satisfies(contains($t, .))">
       <xsl:message>{document-uri($doc)} contains {.}</xsl:message>
```

Actually you could replace the xsl:if test by `test="contains($doc, .)"` but it might be less efficient if the documents are large, since it involves assembling the whole string value of the document as a string in memory.

Another alternative would be to process the files as unparsed text files rather than XML files, but that would require some tinkering with the Saxon configuration so it doesn't automatically parse files with a '.xml' file extension as XML.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm a bit confused by the example you shared due to my inexperience with XSL. I've updated my question. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't bother closing the elements because I was in a hurry and I assumed you could sort that out. Obviously every start tag needs a corresponding end tag. Also the curly brace notation in xsl:message is XSLT 3.0 and requires you to put expand-text="yes" on the xsl:stylesheet element.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction - I don't want to use up a lot of your time! hopefully someone will come along and help me figure out the looped query syntax and it'll be ready to go! cheers